# How can I use url variable as url in code

Tags: python, string-formatting

```py
URL = input("Plz enter you Url")

import os

os.system("youtube-dl -f 95  -g **URL**")
```

I asked user for a `url` and I want to use the provided `url` on line 3

Comment: You can probably do something like `os.system(f"youtube-dl -f 95  -g {URL}")`

Comment: per PEP8 all imports should be at the top of the file also you seem to need to cover some Python basics

Answer (score 1):

Use string formatting:

```py
URL = input("Plz enter you Url")

import os

os.system(f"youtube-dl -f 95  -g {URL}")
```

Comment: how can i get output of code in python

Answer (score 0):

You can use .format in python

so

```
URL = input("Plz enter you Url")

import os

os.system("youtube-dl -f 95  -g {}".format(URL))
```

Comment: "old" method and it's slower and less readable than `f` strings